# Convert select to radio button to customize a card style

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hello and I already want to apologize in advance for my English ^^

I am trying to modify a list in radio button.
This would allow me to give a card style for each template choice.

I don't want to use a script to modify the code when launching the page but to change the html directly

[Preview approaching my final wish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikMHH.gif)

Thank you in advance for your help

Here is my little piece of code

```js
const setTheme = (theme) => {
  document.documentElement.className = theme;
  localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);
}

document.getElementById('theme-select').addEventListener('change', function() {
  setTheme(this.value);
});

const getTheme = () => {
  const theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
  theme && setTheme(theme);
}
 
getTheme();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap');

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  :root {
    --bg-color: blue;
    --text-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
}
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --bg-color: red;
    --text-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
}

:root,
:root.light {
  --bg-color: #fff;
  --text-color: #123;
}

:root.dark {
  --bg-color: #121212;
  --text-color: #696d7d;
}

:root.blue {
  --bg-color: #05396B;
  --text-color: #E7F1FE;
}

:root.pink {
  --bg-color: #ffcad4;
  --text-color: #e75480;
}

:root.space {
  --bg-color: #000;
  --text-color: #f2bd16;
  --bg-url: url("https://www.spacejam.com/1996/img/bg_stars.gif");
  --font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
}

:root.nyan {
  --bg-color: #013367;
  --text-color: #fff;
  --bg-url: url("https://static.wixstatic.com/media/4cbe8d_f1ed2800a49649848102c68fc5a66e53~mv2.gif");
  --font-family: 'Comic Neue', cursive;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  background-image: var(--bg-url);
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-family: var(--font-family, "Inter", sans-serif);
}

select {
  padding: 0.25rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-family: inherit;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  color: var(--text-color);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<select name="theme-select" id="theme-select">
   <option value="light">Light</option>
   <option value="dark">Dark</option>
   <option value="blue">Blue</option>
   <option value="pink">Pink</option>
   <option value="space">Space</option>
   <option value="nyan">Nyan</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You mentioned that, you don't want to use script. That means don't you want to use javascript?

Comment: So you need to use radio element instead of select element? (You mention that you need a card style)

Comment: @Prana I have updated my post just below to try to explain in more detail

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make radio element as card, you need to style them. Following are the html

```
<label class="container">
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark">Light</span>
</label>
<label class="container">
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark">Dark</span>
</label>
<label class="container">
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark">Blue</span>
</label>
<label class="container">
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark">Pink</span>
</label>
<label class="container">
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark">Space</span>
</label>
<label class="container">
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark">Nyan</span>
</label>
```

Then I've added some styles to them.

```
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

/* Hide the browser's default radio button */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Create a custom radio button */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the radio button is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the indicator (the dot/circle - hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the indicator (dot/circle) when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the indicator (dot/circle) */
.container:after {
    z-index: 10
}
```

I put them in codepen https://codepen.io/jegatheesprana/pen/BaRxJpb

**As you asked in the comment, if you want to set the checked value for a theme value, use the function**

```
const checkInput = (theme) => {
    document.querySelector('input[value="' + theme + '"]').checked = true
}
```

Comment: Wow awesome, that's exactly it. Thank you very much Do you know what to modify on the current script to make it compatible with? Because it works for a list but for its modifications.
Thank you for you help

Comment: I have modified my code pen code. Can you check it?

Comment: Yes it works wonderfully, really beautiful. How can I leave the theme active with an .active for example? To find out which theme is currently active.

Anyway, thank you very much for your help

Comment: You mean, you want to check which input element is active now?

Comment: Yes, if the "dark" theme is active, that the "dark" radio is selected.
Afterwards the code will be perfect :)
You are really fast ^^

Comment: I have added that one in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have achieved something, do you think this is right ?
How I could keep the theme active select from this list ? So that if I selected "dark", this one remains selected in the list (just to see which one is active)

```js
const setTheme = (theme) => {
  document.documentElement.className = theme;
  localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);
}

const getTheme = () => {
  const theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
  theme && setTheme(theme);
}
 
getTheme();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap');

:root,
:root.light {
  --bg-color: #fff;
  --text-color: #123;
}

:root.dark {
  --bg-color: #121212;
  --text-color: #696d7d;
}

:root.blue {
  --bg-color: #05396B;
  --text-color: #E7F1FE;
}

:root.pink {
  --bg-color: #ffcad4;
  --text-color: #e75480;
}

:root.space {
  --bg-color: #000;
  --text-color: #f2bd16;
  --bg-url: url("https://www.spacejam.com/1996/img/bg_stars.gif");
  --font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
}

:root.nyan {
  --bg-color: #013367;
  --text-color: #fff;
  --bg-url: url("https://static.wixstatic.com/media/4cbe8d_f1ed2800a49649848102c68fc5a66e53~mv2.gif");
  --font-family: 'Comic Neue', cursive;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  background-image: var(--bg-url);
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-family: var(--font-family, "Inter", sans-serif);
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2.5rem 0;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
}

select {
  padding: 0.25rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-family: inherit;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  color: var(--text-color);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

/* Hide the browser's default radio button */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Create a custom radio button */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the radio button is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the indicator (the dot/circle - hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the indicator (dot/circle) when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the indicator (dot/circle) */
.container:after {
    z-index: 10
}
```

```html
<label class="container">
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="theme-select" onclick="setTheme(this.value)" value="light">
  <span class="checkmark">Light</span>
</label>
<label class="container">
  <input type="radio" name="theme-select" onclick="setTheme(this.value)" value="dark">
  <span class="checkmark">Dark</span>
</label>
<label class="container">
  <input type="radio" name="theme-select" onclick="setTheme(this.value)" value="blue">
  <span class="checkmark">Bleu</span>
</label>
```